# bad results NDVI in rasterio with jp2 sentinel-2 bands

Tags: sentinel-2, jpeg-2000, rasterio

I am using 2 Sentinel-2A bands to compute the NDVI. Here is my code:

```py
import os, rasterio

outfile = r'some\path\ndvi.tif'
#url to the bands
b4 = 'http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/30/T/TK/2017/4/12/0/B04.jp2'
b8 = 'http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/30/T/TK/2017/4/12/0/B08.jp2'

#open the bands (I can't believe how easy is this with rasterio!)
with rasterio.open(b4) as red:
    RED = red.read()
with rasterio.open(b8) as nir:
    NIR = nir.read()

#compute the ndvi
ndvi = (NIR-RED)/(NIR+RED)
#print(ndvi.min(), ndvi.max()) The problem is alredy here

profile = red.meta
profile.update(driver='GTiff')
profile.update(dtype=rasterio.float32)

with rasterio.open(outfile, 'w', **profile) as dst:
    dst.write(ndvi.astype(rasterio.float32))
```

The problem is that, this is working fine, except for negative values. It seems that the num (NIR-RED) gets positives values no matter what. So vegetation and all the ndvi values between 0 and 1 keeps good values, but ndvi values between 0 and -1 gets weird values. 
I can solve this saving RED and NIR to 2 GTiff rasters in local, but I guess that there must be one solution in order to avoid to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because these bands come as unsigned integer 16 so the numpy division returns only positive integers.

You can replace `ndvi = (NIR-RED)/(NIR+RED)` by `ndvi = (NIR.astype(float) - RED.astype(float)) / (NIR+RED)`